# Programmatically adding menu + items to NSPopupButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite, nspopupbutton

I have a custom class "BackupIncrement" which gets its data from an sqlite3 database, and works just fine. I also have an `NSPopUpButton` called "pubDefaultIncrement" which is hooked up in `IB`.

The end result is that I would like to have the `popupbutton` populate with meaningful titles and also with each `menuitem` or value being the increment id (primary key) from the database.

Here is the code in question:

```
- (void)doAddItemsTopubDefaultBackupIncrement {
    marBackupIncrement = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    pubDefaultIncrement = [[NSPopUpButton alloc] init];
    [pubDefaultIncrement removeAllItems];
    mnuBackupIncrement = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
    const char* chrSQLSelect = "SELECT * FROM _backup_increments";
    sqlite3_stmt* compiledSQL;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(claAppDelegate.sl3Database, chrSQLSelect, -1, &compiledSQL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(compiledSQL) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            BackupIncrement* bi = [[BackupIncrement alloc]
                            initWithintIncrementId:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledSQL, 0)]
                            AndstrIncrementValue:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledSQL, 1)]
                            AndstrIncrementDescription:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledSQL, 2)]];
            NSMenuItem* mi = [[NSMenuItem alloc]
                            initWithTitle:[bi strIncrementValueDescription]
                            action:Nil
                            keyEquivalent:[bi strIncrementValue]];
            [mi setTarget:self];
            [mi setRepresentedObject:bi];
            [mi setTag:[[bi intIncrementId] integerValue]];
            [mnuBackupIncrement addItem:mi];
            NSLog(@"Menu Item: %@", mi);
            NSLog(@"Menu Item Title: %@", [mi title]);
            NSLog(@"Menu Item Tag: %ld", (long)[mi tag]);
            //[[pubDefaultIncrement menu] addItem:mi];
            //[marBackupIncrement addObject:bi];
        }
    }
    //NSLog(@"%@", mnuBackupIncrement);
    //[pubDefaultIncrement setTarget:self];
    [[pubDefaultIncrement menu] setSupermenu:mnuBackupIncrement];
    [pubDefaultIncrement setMenu:mnuBackupIncrement];
}
```

The sql works, it loops 5 times fetching each of the rows from the sqlite3 table.

This:

```
NSLog(@"%@", mnuBackupIncrement);
```

prints out the menu object with the 5 menu item objects inside it.

However when I run my project code the popupbutton has 3 things.

```
1st: a blank item
2nd: Item 2
3rd: Item 3
```

I was originally attempting this with an ArrayController and Bindings but I couldn't seem to get the tags for each menu item to work properly. If that is the way to do this, I would gladly listen to the proper way to the bindings.

Just f.y.i. the BackupIncrement object exposes 4 properties:

```
intIncrementId: the primary key from the table (1-5 currently for the 5 rows)
strIncrementValue: the single letter value from the table (h, d, w, m, y)
strIncrementDescription: the desc for the value (hour, day, week, month, year)
strIncrementValueDescription: a combination of the previous two - e.g. "d (day)", "m (month)"
```

So again - ideally id have the NSPopUpButton populate with menuitems which have strIncrementValueDescription as the visible "content" and the corresponding intIncrementId as the "value" such that when an item is selected I can get the tag or whichever an then act accordingly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think your approach is slightly off.  First create a model to contain the data from the sqlite3 database.  This fetch should be done only once.  Then create an object that implements the `NSMenuDelegate` protocol and set the popup button menu delegate to use this object.  It can then translate your model data to a menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out (once again) my issue was a timing one. I was calling the function in question from within the ViewController's initWithNibName...

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        if (!claAppDelegate) {
            claAppDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
        }
        //[self doAddItemsTopubDefaultBackupIncrement]; <--- HERE doesn't work....
    }
    return self;
}
```

When instead I should have been calling it **after** the ViewController has been loaded:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [self viewWillLoad];
    [super loadView];
    [self viewDidLoad]; // <-- call in here instead
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self doAddItemsTopubDefaultBackupIncrement]; //<-- HERE: works just fine...
    [pubDefaultIncrement selectItemWithTag:claAppDelegate.intDefaultBackupIncrmentId];
}
```